Calculate mouse DPI
My script should calculate mouse DPI based on how far the mouse cursor moves. I use the ctypes library. I'm trying to find DPI deviations (my mouse software has DPI set to 900 but it's really 862). I could use a DPI analyzer and measure the distance with a ruler, but I'm trying to take human error out of the equation. The script should track and measure mouse movements and run the calculation.
import ctypes
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import math

# Constants for screen resolution and physical dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH_PX = 2560
SCREEN_HEIGHT_PX = 1440
SCREEN_DIAGONAL_IN = 27.9

# Calculate the screen width and height in inches
screen_width_in = (SCREEN_WIDTH_PX / SCREEN_HEIGHT_PX) * (SCREEN_DIAGONAL_IN / (math.sqrt(1 + (SCREEN_HEIGHT_PX / SCREEN_WIDTH_PX) ** 2)))
screen_height_in = (SCREEN_HEIGHT_PX / SCREEN_WIDTH_PX) * screen_width_in

# Function to calculate DPI
def calculate_dpi(distance_px, distance_in):
    # Check to prevent division by zero
    if distance_in == 0:
        return 0
    return distance_px / distance_in

# Function to convert pixels to inches
def px_to_in(px, axis):
    # Check to prevent division by zero
    if axis == 'x' and screen_width_in != 0:
        return px / (SCREEN_WIDTH_PX / screen_width_in)
    elif axis == 'y' and screen_height_in != 0:
        return px / (SCREEN_HEIGHT_PX / screen_height_in)
    return 0

# Mouse movement callback
def on_move(x, y):
    # Calculate the distance moved in pixels
    distance_px_x = abs(x - SCREEN_WIDTH_PX / 2)
    distance_px_y = abs(y - SCREEN_HEIGHT_PX / 2)

    # Convert pixels to inches
    distance_in_x = px_to_in(distance_px_x, 'x')
    distance_in_y = px_to_in(distance_px_y, 'y')

    # Calculate DPI for both axes
    dpi_x = calculate_dpi(distance_px_x, distance_in_x)
    dpi_y = calculate_dpi(distance_px_y, distance_in_y)

    # Only print DPI if distance_in is not zero
    if distance_in_x > 0 and distance_in_y > 0:
        print(f"Moved {distance_px_x} px (X-axis), which is {distance_in_x:.2f} in")
        print(f"Moved {distance_px_y} px (Y-axis), which is {distance_in_y:.2f} in")
        print(f"DPI (X-axis): {dpi_x:.2f}")
        print(f"DPI (Y-axis): {dpi_y:.2f}")

# Set the process DPI aware to capture the true resolution
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()

# Start capturing mouse movement
with Listener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
    listener.join()

I've tried using a distance reference for PPI using a defined DPI like 900, calculating the PPI for my monitor and measure mouse movement against the reference to get a deviation reading which would be my true DPI.
From PPI the reading I get the same value I set for the reference, or complete nonsense. The idea is measuring the distance between two points like most other DPI analyzers, but instead of physical distances I use specific horizontal pixel lengths, once again measuring the PPI for that length (half my monitor's horizontal resolution, 2560 to 1280) which comes out the same as the PPI for the whole screen (~91.76). The script should measure up to a threshold of 1280 pixels or less and run the calculation.
The "two points" method is separate from this most recent attempt but I've also tried combining the two with more or less the same results.
